# How to visualize effect of running kmeans algorithm in SPSS?

Tags: visualization, k-means, spss

How to visualize effect of runnng kmeans algoritm in SPSS ? I really don't see there any additional graphical options, but I think I've seen some visualizations of kmeans results made in SPSS, which seemed dedicated to kmeans procedure. I would like to visualize values of centers of clusters.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in the cluster silhouette plots available from the STATS CLUS SIL extension command for any clustering method.  Requires the Python Essentials available from the SPSS Community website (www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral) and the command, also from that site.