# Find the optimum number of clusters (in hierarchical clustering)

Tags: spss, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to do cluster analysis in SPSS. In R, we can use silhouette plots to determine the best number of cluster.

How can i find optimum number of cluster using SPSS.

PS. I am new to SPSS.

Comment: A SPSS macro calculating Silhouette coefficient and doing width plot is available in the library "Internal clustering criteria" found on my "Kirill's SPSS macros page".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `STATS CLUS SIL` command to generate silhouette plots and scores if that's specifically what you're after.

Sample syntax, using mostly default values, might look like this:

```
STATS CLUS SIL
 CLUSTER=clus_var /* var w cluster classifications */
 VARIABLES=pred_var1 TO pred_var10 /* vars used to form clusters */
 NEXTBEST=nb_clus_var /* output var. holds next best classifications */
 SILHOUETTE=s_value /* output var. holds silhouette scores */
 DISSIMILARITY=EUCLID /* make sure this matches measure in kmeans */
 MINKOWSKIPOWER=2
 /OPTIONS MISSING=RESCALE RENUMBERORDINAL=NO
 /OUTPUT HISTOGRAM=YES ORIENTATION=HORIZONTAL THREEDBAR=YES THREEDCOUNTS=NO .
```

Potentially helpful links:

[IBM: Using the silhouette procedure to evaluate kmeans](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/381501/using-the-silhouette-procedure-to-evaluate-k-means/)

[stackoverflow: How to visualize the effect of running means algorithm in SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665535/how-to-visualize-effect-of-running-kmeans-algorithm-in-spss)

[Stats.StackExchange: How to Calculate silhouette coefficient in SPSS for clustered data set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112583/how-to-calculate-silhouette-coefficient-in-spss-for-clustered-data-set)

On a side note, you might also consider the `DISCRIMINANT` command as another tool for evaluating the distinctiveness of your clusters.

```
DISCRIMINANT
 /GROUPS=clus_var4 (1 4) /* assumes 4 cluster classifications */
 /VARIABLES=pred_var1 TO pred_var10 /* vars used to form clusters */
 /ANAL all
 /METHOD = MAHAL
 /PRIORS SIZE
 /HISTORY = STEP
 /ROTATE struct
 /STATISTICS = CROSSVALID COEFF
 /CLASSIFY = NONMISSING POOLED .
```

You can look at the output classification stats (cross-validated) to see how often the predicted cluster classification matches the actual.